# How make Escaping Attribute Rendering in case I create a Blade component in Larvavel?

Tags: php, laravel

I learn Laravel and encountered a problem.

There is the next code on the Blade Templates section of the documentation page (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#escaping-attribute-rendering):

```php
<x-button ::class="{ danger: isDeleting }">
    Submit
</x-button>
```

And while it is said that I should get the next outgoing HTML code:

```html
<button :class="{ danger: isDeleting }">
    Submit
</button>
```

But I get the error.

Please, give me a bit of advice on what exactly I should do to get this in output.

I have just made what does the documentation said on that page.

Comment: This example from the doc is for using JS with AlpineJS. With PHP you can use regular php `<x-button :class="$isDeleting ? 'danger' : ''"` and will probably need to merge the class on the component. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, it is appropriate. Thank you pretty much.